# Java Arduino Serial Read

Tags: java, serial-port, arduino, midi

I'm making a Serial to MIDI interface in Java, with the serial data coming from an Arduino and being processed through the RXTX library.
Unfortunately, using the suggested code from Arduino website [link](http://playground.arduino.cc/Interfacing/Java), I'm unable to retrieve the serial data.
The example code uses `Serial.println` on the Arduino side and `BufferedReader.readLine()` on the Java side. In my codeI'm not writing a line through Serial.println, but a MIDI message.

**Arduino**:

```
void MIDI_TX(unsigned char MESSAGE, unsigned char PITCH, unsigned char VELOCITY) 
{
  status = MESSAGE + midichannel;
  Serial.write(status);
  Serial.write(PITCH);
  Serial.write(VELOCITY);
}
```

I tried reading the serial data on a char buffer:

**Java**

```
char buf[] = new char[3];
reader.read(buf);
int channel = (int)buf[0] ;
int key = (int)buf[1] ;
int vel = (int)buf[2] ;
```

but I'm getting weird data...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**SOLVED:**
It was just an error in the `port.setSerialPortParams`, I was writing at baudrate 115200 but reading at 9600.

Comment: Can you mark this answer as accepted, so it doesn't show up on the unanswered questions list?  Thanks.

Comment: NP, thanks for making Stack Overflow a better place!